# How do I specific belongs_to and has_many relationships when generating new models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, orm, associations

It's my first time using Rails and I'm not finding exactly how to generate new models (and migrations) with associations. For example, I have two entities:

- Blog
- Post

One blog can have many posts, and one post belongs to one blog. I'm using the following commands:

```
rails generate model Blog /* properties... */ post:has_many

rails generate model Post /* properties... */ blog:belongs_to
```

But it doesn't work at all (read: the migration and model files are not being generated with the associations). Maybe I'm doing something wrong. Should I create the associations only after I create all my models?

Also, is there a need to declare in both models the relationship, or just in one of them?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When passed as a generator argument `belongs_to` in is just an alias of [`references`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1.7/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/TableDefinition.html#method-i-references) which tells rails to create a column named `blog_id` which is a foreign key:

```
# rails generate model Post blog:belongs_to
class CreatePosts < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :posts do |t|
      t.belongs_to :blog, foreign_key: true
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

This is the actual database column that defines the relation between two tables.

It also adds the association to the model:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :blog
end
```

### Why does'nt the same work for `has_many`?

The arguments for the model generators are attributes of the model. `blog_id` is an actual attribute backed by a database column.
`has_many` is not an attribute. It's a metaprogramming method which adds a `posts` method to your Blog instances. You need to add it manually to the model.

If you run `rails g model Blog posts:has_many foo:bar` Rails will actually create a migration with those attributes:

```
class CreateBlogs < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :blogs do |t|
      t.has_many :posts
      t.bar :foo

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Rails does not type check the arguments. Of course the migration won't actually run:

```
undefined method `has_many' for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQL::TableDefinition:0x007fd12d9b8bc8>
```

If you have already generated the migration just remove the line `t.has_many :posts` and add `has_many :posts` to `app/models/blog.rb`.

Answer (score 0):

For the `belongs_to` relationship you could use:

```
rails generate model Post /* properties... */ blog:references
```

I don't think you have anything for `has_many` relationship since when you're generating the model and table, you don't have to include anything special there. The relationship is in the "belonging" table.

So for that you just use a simple:

```
rails generate model Blog /* properties... */
```

And then manually add the `has_many :posts` in the model afterward :)